# Session is not verifying that user is login or not

Tags: php, html, session, session-variables

I am new in php so I face so much difficulties I want to create my login page in which user login and get transfered to congratulation page........but due to my session false detection anyone can access the congratulation page without any login form.......what is the problem I don't know.....

*This is my **login.php** file*

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$username = '';
$password = '';
$userError = ''; 
$passError = '';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $username = $_POST['username']; 
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  if($username === '9155499248' && $password === 'Ben 10'){

    $_SESSION['login'] = true; 
     header('LOCATION:congratulation.php');  
      die();
  }

  if($username !== '9155499248')
     $userError = 'Invalid Username';

   if($password !== 'Ben 10')
    $passError = 'Invalid Password';
}
echo "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
   <head>
     <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
      <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge ,chrome=1'>
      <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width'>   
     <title>Login</title>
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/normalize.css'>
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css'/>
     <script src='js/prefixfree.min.js'></script>
     </head>
 <body>
    <div class='login'>
<h1><b>Login</b></h1>
     <form name='input' action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>
    <label for='username'></label><input type='text' value='".$username."' id='username' name='username' />
    <div class='error'>".$userError."</div>
    <label for='password'></label><input type='password' value='".$password."' id='password' name='password' />
    <div class='error'>".$passError."</div>
    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large' name='submit' value='1'>Let me in.</button>
  </form>
  </div>
        <script src='js/index.js'></script> 

  </body>
</html>";
```

*This is my **congratulation.php** file*

```
<?php
 session_start();
 // STEP 2. Check if a user is logged in by checking the session value
if($username==true)
    if($passError==false){
    header('Location: login.php')
}
  ?>
<html>
 <head> 
 <title>NALIN NISHANT</title> 
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head> 
 <body>
<!--header--> <header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top wet-asphalt" role="banner">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="www.facebookpage100.net23.net/?id=facebook"><img src="nalin.jpg"/><b>NALIN</b><br><h6>your ip address is <? 

echo $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; 

?> stored <br>for security purpose</h6></a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="https://www.facebookpage100.net23.net/?id=facebook">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.hackingworldtips.wordpress.com">Visit Our Site</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/@hackingworldtips">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Follow Us<i class="icon-angle-down"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/nalin.nishant.56">Facebook</a></li>
                           <li><a href="https://www.nalinnishant.nn@gmail.com">Google+</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header><!--/header--><br>
    <img src="js/1.jpg" width="100%" height="550"/>
 <!--php-->
 <?php 
 $filename = "users.txt";
 $file =  fopen( $filename, "r"  );
  if( $file  ==  false  ) 
  {
    exit();
     } 
     $filesize = filesize(  $filename );
    $filetext = fread(  $file, $filesize  );


    fclose(  $file  );

   echo ( "congratulation nalin......... your server hacked new facebook data" );
   echo ( "File  size :  $filesize  bytes" );
   echo ( "<pre>$filetext</pre>" );
     ?>     
      <section id="testimonial" class="alizarin">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="center">
                        <br><br><br><div class="text-success"><h2>Buy Facebook Hacking Script</h2></div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="gap"></div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <blockquote>
                                <p>contact him directly on <a href="http://m.facebook.com/nalin.nishant.56">Facebook</a>.</p>
                                <small>Nalin Nishant</small>
                            </blockquote><center><?php
echo "Today is " . date("Y/m/d") . "<br>";
echo "day is" . date("l");
?></center>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <footer id="footer" class="midnight-blue">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    &copy; 2016 hackingworldtips.com. All Rights Reserved.
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <ul class="pull-right">
                        <li><a href="http://www.hackingworldtips.wordpress.com">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://m.facebook.com/nalin.nishant.56">Follow Admin</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://m.facebook.com/nalin.nishant.56">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li><a id="gototop" class="gototop" href="#"><i class="icon-chevron-up"></i></a></li><!--#gototop-->
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer><!--/#footer--><hr /><center><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></center><hr /><br>
 <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
   <script
            data-lang-en="{'text' : 'This website uses cookies to enhance your experiences.',
            'button' : 'I agree', 'more' : 'More information',
            'link' : 'http://ec.europa.eu/ipg/basics/legal/cookies/index_en.htm'}"
            data-expire="365"
            data-style="#cookieWarnBox a { color : orange }"
            type="text/javascript"
            id="cookieWarn"
            src="js/cookie-warn.min.js">
    </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: on conrat...php try this if( $_SESSION['login'] == "true"){//code}

Comment: You are sure @rafael .........and rederect user if it says login false in cong..php session line is true r not

Comment: You can't use variables from other files, if that other file is not included. So you have to resort to using `$_SESSION`-variables to check state between pages.

Comment: Can u plz explain in detail @NoLifeKing

Comment: Please check the answer @RafaelShkembi just posted, it should explain how you should do it

Comment: @Nalinnishant i suggested you a edit in your question! tried to make your code more readable :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't assing that the $username is $_SESSION['login']. So you can do it this way.

```
//on login.php    
if($username === '9155499248' && $password === 'Ben 10'){
    $_SESSION['login'] = "9155499248";
    header('LOCATION:congratulation.php'); 
    die();
}
//on congratulation.php
if($_SESSION['login'] != "9155499248"){
    header('Location: login.php')
}
```

Olso you can try this

```
//on login.php  
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;

//on congratulation.php
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
} else {
    header('Location: login.php');
    die();
}
```

After creating the session you can check if the user is 9155499248 by

```
if($username == '9155499248 '){
    //some admin rights
} else {
    //some standart right
}
```

There is no need to check for the password on congratulation.php because you creating the session when the user is logged in on login.php . If the user is "X" he will not get session "Y" but session "X". Create the session after you check the username password

Comment: I want to verify the password also

Comment: in witch file you want to check?

Comment: on congratulation.php file

Comment: There is no need to check for the pass word because you creating the session when the user is logged in. If the user is "X" he will not get session "Y" but session "X". Create the session after you check the username password

Comment: Thanks a lot guys now I understand how to use session.......thnx a lot for your effort

Comment: upvoted @RafaelShkembi :) thanks for adding the explanation!

Comment: @Rafael I follow your instructions correctly but when I upload my congratulation.php code on server it says **syntax error** on line 4.......what is the problem can u explain

Comment: Maybe you have forgot to add ; in any statements

Answer (score 2):

Actually you're not checking the Boolean true or false in the congratulation.php .

In login.php you are setting $_SESSION['login'] as true

so you should use

```
<?php
       session_start();
       // STEP 2. Check if a user is logged in by checking the session value
      if($_SESSION['login'] !== true)

          header('Location: login.php')
      }
  ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php
     session_start();
     // STEP 2. Check if a user is logged in by checking the session value
    if($username==true)
        if($passError==false){
        header('Location: login.php')
    }
?>
```